# How to render form in Bootstrap modal in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal in my Rails app. The code I have right now:

Index page:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-amount="30" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Process Payment</button>

    <%= render 'point_transactions/payment'%>
```

Jquery Bootstrap modal:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

My form processing Braintree Payment

```html
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <%=form_for point_transactions_path, url: point_transactions_path do |f| %>
        <div id="payment-form"></div>
        <br>
          <%=f .submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg' %>
            <%end%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  braintree.setup('____', "dropin", {
    container: "payment-form"
  });
</script>
```

Every time I load index page, I also render the payment form. If I click on the button, the jQuery modal will pop up the form.

1. How I can render the form AFTER user will click on the button - I guess it will be in the jQuery?
2. My button include data-amount="30". How I can pass the parameter data-amount to my controller through the jQuery?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You can do it but just let us know from where you are rendering `form`? You are planning to send request back to server and get a `form` view and then render?

Comment: Currently I don't have any new in my controller and I am rendering the form in the index page & def index is carrying the payment token. I think it is not correct way but my intention is to load the popup form as fast as possible.

I tried to redirect it to the new page where it pops up but it was very slow.

Comment: Not much idea on Ruby on rails but I can suggest you to use `ajax` for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved in the following way:

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddPointDialog", function () {

     var myPoint = $(this).data('points');
     $(".modal-body #point_transaction_points").val( myPoint );
});
```

HTML POP UP form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addPointDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%=form_for @point_transaction , url: point_transactions_path do |f| %>
            <div id="payment-form"></div>
            <br>
             <%= f.hidden_field :points %>
          <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-success btn-lg' %>
          <%end%>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Button

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-points="30" class="open-AddPointDialog btn btn-success big" href="#addPointDialog"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right hided-icon big"></i> Buy Points </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an attempt to answer your second question, I am assuming you want to get the value `30` back to your controller.  If this is the case, you could just add it to your url as a query param.

```
form_for point_transactions_path, url: point_transactions_path(amount: 30) do |f|
```

back in your controller you can get to it lik this

```
params[:amount]  #=> 30
```

Comment: Thank you but but my intention is to have more buttons and each should carry different parameter that should be passed to the controller. Any idea how to do it?